# Get the string of the query that fired a trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am creating a control table in a PostgreSQL database, this table should register the query that fired a trigger in a specific table. For instance

if I do

```
insert into employees('bob');
```

I would like to be able to capture the string 'insert into employees('bob');' inside a trigger associated with employees table. It doesn't matter if the trigger is before or after.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [`current_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) in the trigger function.

```
insert into control_table(query_text) 
select current_query();
```

The trigger should be `for each statement`.