# Get query that caused a trigger SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to know how to get the string of the query that caused a trigger to fire in SQLite. I've found solutions for SQL, but not SQLite.

Comment: where did you look? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: @nbk I couldn't find the answer on that page

Comment: I am unsure that this is possible, in SQLite or in other RDBMS. What is the solution that you have found? Even if it is not applicable to SQLite, it might help someone come up with a SQLite solution.

Comment: @GMB https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014983/9178447

Comment: You know what the result of your trigger is, so you check the result table for the right conditions, so you have an insert or update that causes that trigger and produces one result, that that you see. It is like backswords engineering. Depending on what the trigger statement is, there can be only a handfull odf possible rows. It is not perfect, but as long you don't have transaction logs.

Comment: @jimmyruby: I see. This is a postgres solution that only works for statement-level triggers... that are not supported in SQLite (it only allows row-level triggers). Chances are that there is no solution for SQLite...